# Rails OAuthException :: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-oauth, fb-graph

Iam using [**fb_graph**](https://github.com/nov/fb_graph) in my rails application to get and set the access token if it authenticates with facebook. I have an Invites controller where a user will have to authenticate to invite friends. My code looks like this:

```
 def facebook
   if params[:code]
     set_oauth_token(params[:code])
   elsif params[:error]
     redirect_to landing_path, :alert => "Access Denied"
     return
   end

   if current_user.oauth_token.nil?
     redirect_to client.authorization_uri(
     :scope => "user_about_me, email, publish_stream, user_location, user_interests, user_birthday, user_likes, user_hometown, offline_access"
      )
   end

 private

 def set_oauth_token(token)
   client.authorization_code = params[:code]
   access_token = client.access_token! :client_auth_body
   user = FbGraph::User.me(access_token).fetch
   current_user.oauth_token = access_token
   current_user.save(:validate => false)
 end

  def client
    FbGraph::Auth.new(ENV["FACEBOOK_KEY"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"], :redirect_uri =>  invites_facebook_url).client
  end
```

But Iam getting the error:

```
 FbGraph::InvalidRequest at /invites/facebook
 OAuthException :: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

The error is at the following line:

```
user = FbGraph::User.me(access_token).fetch
```

I tried to look for a solution and modified the code but still couldn't able to resolve the problem. Its all that the oauth token is not valid.

Please help me find a solution. Many thanks!!

Comment: Did you coding something like this before and that was working?

Comment: @kspacja I git the solution and posted my answer. You can check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the error wchich was that after the callback you have to hit the facebook again to get the oauth token. I have modified my code and it worked.

*User model*

```
def self.auth(redirect_url)
    FbGraph::Auth.new(ENV["FACEBOOK_KEY"], ENV["FACEBOOK_SECRET"], :redirect_uri =>  redirect_url)
end
```

*User controller*

```
def facebook
  if params[:code]
    set_oauth_token(params[:code])
  elsif params[:error]
    redirect_to landing_path, :alert => "Access Denied"
    return
  end

  if current_user.oauth_token.nil?
    client = User.auth(invites_facebook_url).client
    redirect_to client.authorization_uri(
    :scope => "user_about_me, email, publish_stream, user_location, user_interests, user_birthday, user_likes, user_hometown, offline_access"
    )
 end
end

private

  def set_oauth_token(token)
    client = User.auth(invites_facebook_url).client
    client.authorization_code = params[:code]
    access_token = client.access_token! :client_auth_body
    user = FbGraph::User.me(access_token).fetch
    current_user.oauth_token = access_token
    current_user.save(:validate => false)
  end
```